# How to find to which product a process belongs to?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

I need to get information about the product of a process.
As an example, I need to know whether the process `WINWORD` belongs to Office 2010 or Office 2013. Another example would be with the software of adobe creative suite.
In general for a process, which name can be the same for different suites, how to find out the suite version.

In a service I have a list of process names, retrieved from a server. I track for how long a user has been using these process and send this info back to the server. Because the service will be installed in several computers, the Office suite, the Adobe suite or any other product, may be different, but the process is likely to be named the same in each suite.
Currently, in the server I have no way to identify to which version the process belongs to. It a requierement to be able to show for how long, for example, Microsoft Word 2010 has been used and so for each version

I hope I'm being clear.

---

Thanks @Niels for your contribution, which is to retrieve a process `MajorPart` from it's `FileVersionInfo`.
We can send this info as an addition. Surely it makes it simple to identify a suites like Office, where all the products versions major part are the same, butt...
With the adobe list you've showed me that in a adobe suite most products will have a different mayor versions and that's what we're affraid of with checking a process `FileVersionInfo`. Having to setup in the server a way to link each product's major version with the suite just for adobe, means that such thing has to be done for each software in the same or similar situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look into the file properties, as also exposed by Explorer:

[image: Word 2013 versioning]

To retrieve this data in .NET you inspect a [`FileVersionInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo(v=vs.110).aspx) instance as returned by [`FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo(v=vs.110).aspx). Samples are provided on both help pages, but the easiest would be for your case as you're only interested in the major version numbers:

```
    // Get the file version for the notepad.
    FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo =
        FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\Notepad.exe");

    // Print the product major part number.
    textBox1.Text = "Product major part number: " + myFileVersionInfo.ProductMajorPart;
```

Build numbers themselves are well documented for good software suites [like MS Office](https://buildnumbers.wordpress.com/office/).

Comment: We were considering on getting information from the `Process.MainModule`, you can get the `FileName` (full path) and the `FileVersionInfo` directly from there.

Comment: But I wasn't 100% sure this could be the same for other suites, like adobe's CS or AutoCAD.
But maybe just using the major part number could work, it does seem reasonable for the executables to have that unique per version.

Comment: [It's convention](http://semver.org/)  ;)  Not that Microsoft adheres to semantic versioning, but the base principles are universal that the *major* version number indicates major breakage. And that the major and minor combined always indicate a 'shipped version' of a product. For Adobe there are [similar lists available](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/46395-adobe-cs-and-cc-version-number-translation).

Comment: [As does Autocad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD#File_formats_and_versions).

Comment: Did not meant just Autocad, but the whole AutoCAD Design Suite, which has more products under the same license.  
Please read the edit I've made to the post.
I guess all I have left to do is more research about the software the client has installed, check how the versions go in the suites, and figure out a way to improve the models in the server to accomodate the results of my research.